# Add new datas into existing scope-angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have started to learn angularjs, I am trying to insert new values on **button** click with **existing scope**.
I have one button in my page,whenever I click that button **$scope.options** method triggered some datas need to be added into a scope variable to use it on ng-repeat.

For first click its adding directly because there is no-existing data.
When I click next time new values should be added with existing scope.

Here is what i have tried,

```
$scope.options=function(options){           
    //$scope.datas=[];
    //$scope.datas.push(options);
    //$scope.datas = $scope.datas.concat(options)
    $scope.datas=options;
    console.log($scope.datas);          
}
```

For first click of button my scope looks like this,

```
$scope.datas=["IARZ1DS099","CATL0DS32","IARZ1DS13","IATL0DS099","CARZ1DS099"];
```

Can anyone let me know how can I do it?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are assigning value `$scope.datas=options;`. You need to push value to  `$scope.datas` array;

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.options = function (options) {
          if (!$scope.datas) {
            $scope.datas = ["IARZ1DS099", "CATL0DS32", "IARZ1DS13", "IATL0DS099", "CARZ1DS099"]
          } else {
            $scope.datas.push("new value")
          }
          //console.log($scope.datas);
        }
      })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="options()">
      add Data
    </button>
    <div ng-repeat="data in datas track by $index">
      {{data}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: am getting `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` error.

Comment: Declare ` $scope.datas = [];` at the top. See how I declared.

Comment: if i declare like that,each time am getting length as 0

Answer (score 1):

Use `JavaScript` [concat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) method.

Whats wrong in your code is, you are assigning the new set of records directly to your array, which overwrites your existing array with new data. What you require exactly is concatenating your array with new set of datas and reassign the same to the existing array.

```
$scope.datas = $scope.datas.concat(options);
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.datas = ["IARZ1DS099"];
    
    $scope.options = function(options){  
      console.log('Before concat -- ', $scope.datas);
      $scope.datas = $scope.datas.concat(options);
      console.log('After concat -- ', $scope.datas);
    }
    
    $scope.options(["CATL0DS32","IARZ1DS13","IATL0DS099","CARZ1DS099"]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

</div>
```

Comment: it does't work to me. throws `concat` not defined error.

Comment: @user7566666 can you check my solution? Just to make sure that we are in same line.

Comment: its not concatinating,inserts as new array only :-(

Comment: @user7566666 Have you checked my solution console? At first it logs the existing array with only one element, after the array has been concatenated with new 4 values, the new console displays 5 elements, that is one from existing array and 4 from new concatenation. Please verify.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution.

```
$scope.options=function(options){               
    if (!$scope.datas) {
        $scope.datas =options;
    } else {
        for(i=0;i<options.length;i++){
            $scope.datas.push(options[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

@user7566666 thanks for your help.

Comment: What you are doing now is the manual operation for array.concat.